# How to safely remove Umbraco 7 admin UI

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

As a security measure, I am trying to remove the admin UI from an Umbraco 7 site without affecting the front end of the site. I have tried deleting both Umbraco and Umbraco_Client folders (I seem to remember this was how you removed a pre Umbraco 7 site) but the front end of the site errors due to various files that are now missing.

In an ideal scenario I would like to update the content from a staging server and import the database back into the live site, but also I would like to avoid solving this with folder permissions.

Can anyone offer me some advice on the best way to remove the admin UI safely?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to have a separation of environment between content entry and delivery? Not sure if you've seen it but this discussion on the Umbraco forum has some suggestions (but no ideal solutions in my opinion) for that

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/33337-Creating-a-content-editing-and-content-delivery-environment

You could always just do some URL restriction on the server but there's no ideal way as far as I can see

Carl